# Sharepoint top link bar link permissions

Tags: top-link-bar

I have Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and need to hide on of the links from all users and make it visible only for specific users?

I had to delete on of the links created along with a Site it was linking to(it was only visible to people intended to see it). When I recreated it manually, I got into a problem that people that not suppose to see that link(bacause they don't have permission to access that site) can see it.

Only thing I noticed is that when going to Site Settings--> Top link bar--> click on link one I recreated can be edited, other links that were created along with a sites they are linking to can not be edited and a Type the Web address field is greyed out for them.

Answer (score 3):

your last comment was the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much. Here is the Powershell Skript to ensure that somebody else can find it in the future:

```
$w = get-spweb http://site/site
$nav = $w.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
$newLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode -argumentlist @("New Link", "/new-link/default.aspx")
$nav.AddAsLast($newLink)
```

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the auto-generated top links, you can only delete them. They are designed to populate all the links of the subsites that the current web has. If you do not like a specific site or sub-web on the top link bar, just delete it. You can create other links as needed.

As far as your issue of specific people having access to a link, you may be looking at the possible solution differently. If you want to restrict a site for a group of specific users, just uninherit that site's permissions from the root level, add the group of users to it, and display the link on the root site. Only those that will be able to navigate to that site will be able to see it. This also has to do with the auto-generated top link bar I mentioned earlier.

Comment: "Only those that will be able to navigate to that site will be able to see it."
This is a case with auto-generated top links. But not with my manually added link. Now everyone, not only people that are alowed to navigate that site can see that link.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?  "Type the Web address" filed is "/subsite".

Comment: I found a sollution- receating that auto-generated link, as it appered that security trimming doesn't work for manually created links.
Take a look at http://www.bryonbrewer.com/?p=261.